# java.lang.NullPointerException encountered

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have seen many answers with respect to the above error in Java, however most of them are telling what the error is, and I cannot find a way to correct it.

This is a snippet of my code in Java:

```
public static void optimalAlignmentScoreBU(String r, String s, int matchScore, int transition, int transversion, int indel) {

        int m = r.length();
        int n = s.length();
        Node[][] strg = new Node[m + 1][n + 1];

        // base cases
        strg[m][n].val = 0;
}
```

I get error at the line where I write strg[m][n].val =0;
I have created a Node class as follows:

```
// ELEMENT OF DP MATRIX IS OF TYPE NODE
    public class Node {
        int val;
        ArrayList<Pair<Integer>> arrows = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer>>();
    }

// PAIR CLASS
public static class Pair<T> {
        T p1;
        T p2;

        public Pair(T p1, T p2) {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
        }
    }
```

Can you tell me what is going wrong? Why is NULL being pointed? What can I do to correct this?

Comment: `strg[m][n] ` is null

Comment: `strg[m][n]` is null, so you can't access its `.val` field. Arrays are initialized with null values, you need to create a Node you'll put at that index, the node is what you'll be able to call `.val` on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a matrix of null Nodes.

```
    strg[m][n] = new Node();
    strg[m][n].val = 0; // Now there is a Node, no longer NPE.
```

Of course nicer is:

```
    Node node = new Node();
    node.val = 0;
    strg[m][n] = node;
```

where a new Node actually has its val field already 0.

Of course all matrix nodes must be created.

In java:

```
int[] v = new int[10]; // All 0.
boolean[] v = new boolean[10]; // All false.
String[] v = new String[10]; // All null.
double[] v = new double[10];  // All 0.0.
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! So how should I create my matrix, like of what type? As right now I have created like ->  Node[][] strg = new Node[m + 1][n + 1]; Should this be changed?

Comment: That is fine, but then `for (int i = 0; i < m+1; ++i) for (int j = 0; j < n+1; ++j) strg[i][j] = new Node();`. Not nice. As `strg[i][j]` was null.

Comment: So this is a good method to initialize all the cells of my matrix?

Comment: If you use all. Depends, sometimes one assigns new Node objects, and the old value was irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

`strg` is empty; all its values are `null`. You need to create a `new Node`.

When you created an array of non-primitives in java, it doesn't contain any actual objects yet--every item is `null`.

Answer (score -1):

NPE is when you call a methode on a null object ... use the debbuger and see where he is null

Comment: Your message doesn't fit into an answer but more in a comment.